# Start Rails console on OpsWorks with environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, environment-variables, rails-console, aws-opsworks

I am SSH'd into an OpsWorks Rails App Server and I'm trying to start the Rails console.

This is what I do:

```
cd /srv/www/appname/current/
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

But I get an error because the settings file is expecting environment variables to be present from the OpsWorks config, but they aren't:

```
in `fetch': key not found: "ELASTICSEARCH_URL" (KeyError)
```

Form this code:

```
elasticsearch_url: <%= ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_URL') %>
```

The app starts fine and I can use the search feature, so the env vars are clearly getting to the webserver OK. However, when I run `printenv` from the command line, there is no sign of them. How can I start the console and include the env vars that OpsWorks has provided to the webserver (Unicorn)?

Comment: if you read this blog post it appears those variables are not made available to the shell (http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx2G95J53SKI2E0/AWS-OpsWorks-supports-application-environment-variables )

Comment: I think this may be a dup of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776805/aws-opsworks-environment-variables-not-working)... but it's funny because your question was asked first. ANYWAY, I think I answered your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29080651/224334