# AWS OpsWorks Environment variables not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-opsworks

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit Rails Application and I am unable to access my App environment variables.

In OpsWorks App panel, I set my environment variables, say:

```
MYKEY: 1234
```

Then I save and deploy my app again to make these visible.

In my Rails app, or the rails console I get nil:

```
$ bundle exec rails c production
>ENV["MYKEY"]
=> nil
```

I have tried restarting the server. I'm not sure what I am missing, I have been using environment variables in other services.

How can I trace where these should be set?

Comment: If I ssh in and run `sudo opsworks-agent-cli get_json` I do see the MYKEY is there `{  "deploy": { "server": { "environment": { "MYKEY": "1234" } .. `

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Comment: Weird thing is it turned out it works in the Passenger production instances, but doesn't work when I `$ bundle exec rails c production` as deploy user (Which is the same user Passenger is running under). Apache is running under www-data, but if I sign in as either www-data or deploy I don't see any env vars set. So I'm running, but I have no idea what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Are you sayin in application you have the access to the ENV variables?

Comment: Yes. And I also see them in the output log when running deploy in opsworks portal (not sure if I saw them there when I first posted)

Comment: Great, I will check now

Comment: I answered with more details and with a full how-to-do guide. Please check out that and think about to mark it as the right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpsWorks stores environmental variables in different places depending on what kind of app you're deploying. On Rails / Passenger they should be saved in the Apache config file `#{your_app_name}.conf`. ([Source](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/apache2/definitions/web_app.rb#L33))

This means they aren't available in your normal shell environment.

I know the Node.js recipes stored everything in an `/srv/www/#{app_name}/shared/app.env` file... which is then sourced to pull in the environment to run the Node server. This implementation detail also meant you could write shell scripts that sourced that `app.env` file, then called some Node script or whatever.

Of course, Rails isn't Node. I have no idea if the environmental variables are also stored somewhere else or not: a quick look at the Rails recipes in the OpsWorks cookbooks didn't find anything obvious, but maybe I missed something.

Depending on the amount of modifications you have going on in your OpsWorks cookbook, you could create a deploy recipe that does something like this:

`application_environment_file do
    user deploy[:user]
    group deploy[:group]
    path ::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], "shared")
    environment_variables deploy[:environment_variables]
end`

(maybe adjusting the path)

Then to run your console, when you're SSHed into the server, do something like

`sudo source /srv/www/my_app_name/shared/app.env; bundle exec rails console -e production` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the right information! If I view `/etc/apache2/sites-enables/myapp.conf` I do see in there `SetEnv "PKTEST" "testing"` so clearly that is where OpsWorks is actually writing to, and why it can't be seen running rails console.

Comment: I answered with more details and with a full how-to-do guide. Please check out that and think about to mark it as the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

AWS OpsWorks console lets you declare environment variables but **to let them be available for our Rails app we need to use a Chef cookbook recipe plus some precautions.**

In a nutshell we use the **config/secrets.yml** file combined with  **config/application.yml** file, **Figaro gem** and a **Chef cookbook recipe**.
The chef cookbook recipe read the variables defined in OpsWorks console and let them available to Rails app writing the config/application.yml file.

I have published a detailed guide to explain how exactly do it. [Link here](https://medium.com/@diego_durante/opsworks-rails-and-environment-variables-30c6a143253c#.8jlmapsyn).

These are the core points that I covered:

1. Use config/secrets.yml file (added from Rails 4.1)
2. Use Figaro gem to load variables in the environment
3. Declare environment variables inside AWS OpsWorks Console
4. Use a custom Chef recipe to create a config/application.yml file that Figaro will use to let variables available

Answer (score 1):

I (with some help from Bruno at the AWS PopUp Loft in NYC) added some custom Chef code inside the after_restart.rb deploy hook, simply add the folder "deploy" to your apps root directory and inside add "after_restart.eb." In it ....

```
Chef::Log.info("Running deploy/after_restart.rb")

contents = []

node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  deploy[:environment_variables].each do |key, value|
    contents << "export #{key}=\"'#{value}'\""
  end
end


Chef::Log.info("Adding the environment variables to /etc/profile.d/startup_env_config.sh")

bash "create_startup_env_config.sh" do
  user "root"
  cwd  "/etc/profile.d"
  code <<-EOH
    echo \''#{contents.join(" ")}\'' > startup_env_config.sh
    source startup_env_config.sh
    cd #{release_path}

    EOH
  end
```

And that's it. If you update the environment variables inside the OpsWorks  panel remember to restart your instances.

Comment: I tried this recipe but it didn't work! I added my answer below with a full detailed how-to-do guide

Comment: I made a slight change

Comment: Hmm - sorry it didn't work for you. I've been using this method for several months now in a production environment w/o fail. Glad you found an alt solution