# AWS OpsWorks - cannot load rails console. Not loading ENV vars?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-opsworks

when I ssh into the server, and run `sudo RAILS_ENV=integration bundle exec rails c` I get an error stating `Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer`. The `secret_key_base` is set in the OpsWorks interface as an environment variable. Also, if I simply run `sudo bundle exec rails c` (which loads the development env) it loads fine because the secrets.yml has hard coded values in the file.

So I guess my question is, how can I verify that my environment variables are making it to the application? When I deployed the app, and output `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` I get the development secret_key_base, not the one that is loaded in the environment. Or if there is an env variable that doesn't exist in development block in `secrets.yml` the env variable returns `nil` Snippet of secrets.yml below.

Thanks for any help/insight!

```
  integration:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

Comment: Take a look at of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776805/aws-opsworks-environment-variables-not-working/29080651#29080651 , which I think this is a duplicate of. (In OpsWorks on Rails env variables are set via Passenger, but that's not loaded via rails console)

Comment: Thanks, @RyanWilcox I saw that post. I'm trying to refresh the styles via paperclip and when I load the console it doesn't appear to load the api key I have set in OpsWorks.

Comment: Or one way to deal with that is to write out the environmental variables to a file, then source that/file; rails console